# jquery hide/show particular li child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, dom

I have some html like so:

```
<ul id = "postsList">
  <li ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <button class = "deleteButt" ng-click="delButt()">Remove</button>

   <!--hidden div I want to show/hide when the above button is pressed--> 
    <div class = "confirmDeleteBox">
    <button class = "confirmDelete" ng-click = "postDelete(post._id)">Confirm</button>
    </div>

  </li>
</ul>
```

So each post has a `$('.deleteButt')` that you click on and it should show `$('div.confirmDeleteBox')`, including it's child elements, but only for that particular post.

So how would I use jquery to show the hidden children of a particular `li`? Or to show the specific children by their class or id? I'm not sure what the best way to do this is.

Comment: the ng- attributes show that this is a angular.js app. any reason why you want to use only jquery to add this functionality?

Comment: If you are using angular then you don't really need jQuery to do this.

Comment: care to expand fellas? I'm new to angular (and jquery) so I don't know all the functionality. At least give me some terms to google.

Comment: I think the OP would benefit from some code examples of how to do it in Angular as well as jQuery so he can learn of what the equivalent capabilities are of each library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to use jQuery's `siblings()` function.

```
$('.deleteButt').on("click", function (e) {
    $(this).siblings(".confirmDeleteBox").show();
});
```

More detail on this function here: https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Answer (score 4):

Mixing jquery and angularjs (esp in controllers) will result in much pain down the road.  This can be done easily via angular.  `ngRepeat` creates a child scope which allows this to work.

```
<ul id="postsList">
    <li ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <button class="deleteButt" ng-click="showConfirm = !showConfirm" ng-hide="showConfirm">Remove</button>
        <div ng-show="showConfirm">
            <button class="confirmDelete" ng-click="postDelete(post._id)">Confirm</button>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! I plan on doing this. I'm not marking this as the answer though because it's not the question I asked. (but it is the question I should have asked).

Comment: But this is the answer for your question . Mixing jquery with angular is not a good coding practice .